# Command to print the number of *.pdf files in a chosen directory

Tags: grep, ls, wc

I am currently not on a Linux machine. Would the following command produce my wanted result?

`ls | grep ".pdf" | wc`

Comment: not necessarily ending with `.pdf`....this will count all files containing `.pdf`, like image.pdf0001.jpg...

Comment: and ls will list folders as well, if any subfolder contains the `.pdf` characters, those will be counted too.

Comment: and lastly, you should specify what exactly is your wanted result, because the command you've given might produce the wanted result.

Comment: @roaima: the OP asked to count "the *.pdf files", not "the PDF files", so the answers do address the question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, ".pdf" macthes way too much, e.g `foo.pdfa` and `bpdf`.

Furthermore, even if you don't have files wrongly matching, `wc` without options outputs the number of lines, words and bytes in the input, so you would get two numbers more than you're interested in. If you want `grep` in the mix, you could do `ls | grep -E "\.pdf$" | wc -l`, but unless you have a lot of pdf-files in that directory grep isn't needed, you can get by with `ls *.pdf | wc -l`.

**Added later, when I got to think this through:**

Also, `grep` can do the counting so if `grep` is in the mix, just add the `-c` option to grep instead of piping the output to `wc -l`, so `ls | grep -cE "\.pdf$"` or if you want to avoid counting directories named `<something.pdf>`: `ls -l | grep -cE "^-.*\.pdf$"`.

Comment: this will also count folders matching the pattern

Comment: I've added a solution to the answer that addresses that.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
ls | grep ".pdf" | wc -l
```

The `-l` parameter will count only the number of resulted lines, while without the `-l` you would get other counts as well, like newline,  word, and byte count. Note that this will count filenames (and folders as well) which contain the ".pdf" chain of characters.

To count only files ending with `.pdf`, you'd better use `find` :

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Your shell should be able to do the filtering:

```
ls *.pdf | wc -l
```

or you have to make sure you match the end of filenames:

```
ls | grep "*\.pdf$" | wc -l
```

(notice the dollar sign).

Note: both of these will also match *directories* ending in ".pdf", if any.

Note 2: `ls` should behave as if you gave it option `-1` as soon as you pipe its output. Otherwise, add this switch.

Comment: add *ls -1* or you will count lines but not files

Comment: @MolbOrg: see the 2nd note I've just added: `ls` automatically switches to "one-column mode" when you pipe its output.

Comment: Yes, true. didn't  used that. nice to know now. tnx.